# Inserting records in one column as different rows in table1 from different columns in one row of table2 in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have below tables:

```
table1 #TempImagepath
column1 Path nvarchare(800)

table2 SiteImage
column1 SiteID bigint,
column2 Facebookurl nvarchare(800),
column3 Twitterurl nvarchare(800),
column4 Instaurl nvarchare(800)
```

I want to insert data from table2 as different rows into table1 for (Facebookurl,Twitterurl,Instaurl) Where SiteID='10'

Lets say there is one record in table2(SiteImage) as:

```
(10,"/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/WebImages/7ec79e1a-92c2-4d7c-9139-6d177004d766-201701311804409066.jpg","/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/MobileImages/e5ae525f-7dcf-4051-8463-6bb15f520860-201701311804425434.jpg","/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/MobileImages/31d89a5e-5593-4074-881f-d3326b5cf105-201701311804444181.jpg")
```

Then my result shoul give records for table1(#TempImagepath) Something Like:

```
"/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/WebImages/7ec79e1a-92c2-4d7c-9139-6d177004d766-201701311804409066.jpg"
"/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/MobileImages/e5ae525f-7dcf-4051-8463-6bb15f520860-201701311804425434.jpg"
"/uploads/Sites/1/CategoryImages/MobileImages/31d89a5e-5593-4074-881f-d3326b5cf105-201701311804444181.jpg"
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot here

Comment: now see if this is better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,i think this might be useful to you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TempImagepath')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempImagepath
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SiteImage')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE SiteImage

CREATE TABLE #TempImagepath
([Path] nvarchar(800))

CREATE TABLE SiteImage
(
 SiteID bigint IDENTITY,
 Facebookurl nvarchar(800),
 Twitterurl nvarchar(800),
 Instaurl nvarchar(800)
 )
 INSERT INTO SiteImage
 SELECT 'Facebookurl','Twitterurl','Instaur'

INSERT INTO #TempImagepath
SELECT 'Row'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))AS Varchar(10))+': '+  [Path] 
FROM SiteImage
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Facebookurl),(Twitterurl),(Instaurl)
)AS A ([Path])

SELECT * FROM #TempImagepath
```

Result

```
Path
------------------
Row1: Facebookurl
Row2: Twitterurl
Row3: Instaur
```

Comment: Thank you for answering i am working on adding this logic will revert once i am done.